# Kylin Context initialization failed

Tags: kylin

Installed Kylin v1.0 on HDP 2.3 Sandbox, everything is alright but then this error is recorded in the log

```
[localhost-startStop-1]:[2015-09-14 15:07:18,481][ERROR[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContexLoader.java:307)] - Context initialization failed
```

Using Java version "1.7.0_85"

The server starts successfully on port 7070, but displays no page due to the above error. Has anyone come across and solved this type of error while setting up Kylin? If so, please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kylin v1.0 only works with HBase 0.98/0.99. HDP 2.3 ships HBase 1.x and there is a special version of Kylin for it.

Please checkout http://kylin.incubator.apache.org/download/

Look for "Binary Package (for running on HBase 1.1.3 or above)"